# how to aggregate based on month in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like so :

```
Date            headcount1  headcount2
01-jan-17          1             10
02-jan-17          2             11
04-Aug-17          5             7
24-Aug-17          2             8
```

I want to aggregate the headcounts based on each month ,for eg ,the output should be like this :

```
Date            headcount1_sum   headcount2_sum
Jan-17            1+2                  10+11
Aug-17            5+2                  7+8
```

Can someone help me please using sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, sum(headcount1), sum(headcount2)
from t
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') 
order by yyyymm;
```